# Is Azure Blob storage backed up

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have written an application which writes media to and reads media from Azure Blob Storage.

I feel this may be a stupid question but is Azure Blob storage backed up?

Just wondering whether it is necessary to set this up explicitly?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww A typical service is so closely tied to Azure Storage that this question is highly on-topic - it's about expectations about a typical dependency of a typical service.

Comment: Thanks @sharptooth. I was not aware "high coupling" was criteria to evaluate on-topic and off-topic-ness. In fact, I was not aware Azure Storage was on topic because Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. When did system maintenance become on-topic here?

Comment: @jww This is not only a maintenance question, this is a software design question. If you know a service has automatic backups you can make different design decisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is No. Azure Storage does not create back up of your data. This is something you would need to do.

@Pradeep mentions about data replication which is true but please **do not confuse data replication with backup**. Data replication is NOT data backup.

While it is true that a minimum of 3 copies of your blobs are maintained however if you delete the blob, all 3 copies are removed immediately.

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** The data in your Microsoft Azure storage account is always replicated to ensure durability and high availability.

Replication copies your data, either within the same data center, or to a second data center, depending on which replication option you choose. Replication protects your data and preserves your application up-time in the event of transient hardware failures. If your data is replicated to a second data center, it's protected from a catastrophic failure in the primary location.

When you create a storage account, you can select one of the following replication options:

**Locally redundant storage (LRS)**

**Zone-redundant storage (ZRS)**

**Geo-redundant storage (GRS)**

**Read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS)**

For more details, refer “[Azure Storage replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy)”.

Comment: There's a difference between data replication and backup. While it is true that the data is replicated but it is not backed up. Backing up data is user's responsibility.

Comment: As @GauravMantri stated: this *isn't* backup. If you change a blob, the replicas are immediately change. Delete a blob? Replicas are deleted. Replication is solely for *durability* of storage (or read-only access across regions for DR purposes).